# Regex pattern for any integer between -20 and 150 including upto 2 decimals E.g 36.50

Tags: javascript, regex

Want to generate a regex for any integer between -20 and 150 including upto 2 decimals
E.g 36.50
Max value 150.00
and min value -20.00

Have tried this so far but its including -20.78 also and 150.04 also.
I want to limit it to 150.00 and -20.00

```
^((\-([1-9]|1[0-9]|20)(\.\d{2})?)|([0-9]|[1-8][0-9]|9[0-9]|100)(\.\d{2})?)$
```

Can you please help me out ?

Comment: Why not just interpret the string as a number and then do a numeric comparison?

Comment: Maybe just include *20.00* and *150.00* as special cases?
`^(20\.00|150\.00|((\-([1-9]|1[0-9])(\.\d{2})?)|([0-9]|[1-8][0-9]|9[0-9]|100)(\.\d{2})?))$`

Comment: @ Krzysztof Atłasik : This worked :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I vote for just using an inequality, along with a simple regex check to assert that there is no decimal component more precise than hundreths:

```js
var input = "10.35";
if (input >= -20 && input <= 150 &&
    /^-?\d+(?:\.\d{1,2})?$/.test(input)) {
    console.log("MATCH");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this,
instead of taking 20 with all other make it separate

```
^((\-([1-9]|1[0-9])(\.\d{2})?)|((\-(20)(\.(00))|([0-9]|[1-8][0-9]|9[0-9]|100)(\.\d{2})?)$
```